# c# Querying a large readonly table in memory

Tags: c#

Guys I'm stumped on this one,

I have a large table with 100,000 rows of names with 15 columns of integers.

I need to query this table about 50 times or so per request searching for the integers that are less than a certain threshold.

For Example:

Tim: 10, 20, 10, 0, 5, 0

Janet: 20, 10, 20, 0, 0, 0

I would have a query that would find the people who have at least 0, 10, 0, 5, 0.

The bottle neck is of course this query in linq would have to iterate through all of the people

I need a data access strategy (in memory tables, hash tables, dictionary, etc) in order to solve this dilemma. Does anyone have a suggestion??

Comment: which database? i would like to recommend stored procedures, write your iteration logic in stored procedure; this way you don't have to load entire table to memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can be something for you : http://i4o.codeplex.com/
Indexed Linq to Objects, I haven't tried it though, but the idea fits your needs.

Comment: I haven't heard of this yet I will take a look into this

Comment: Nope this actually slowed down the process. I think it's because I'm comparing integers

Comment: OK, and you didn't build the index at the same time as you queried? so the slowness came from building the index?

Comment: Yes I think I'm looking for a different implementation all together. I do appreciate this link though

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to find all the people who have at least a certain value, you're gonna endup having to iterate through all the people at least once.

You could use [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx) to achieve this better.

Comment: I was hoping there may be a more efficient data solution such as a hashtable or something with an index